# Disable sortable item element get stuck in top

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

Please take a look before:
http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/67rZz/

When i'm trying to disable an item and the `item 3` is reaching the top.
you cant put items above it.
what I want to do is that I won't be able to move the `item 3` but that I could put items above it.

how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want the item to remain sortable, but not moveable. See this **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/67rZz/112/)**.
Code:

```
 $(".sortable").sortable({
      items: "li"
    });

 $(".sortable").disableSelection();
 $('.unsortable').mousedown(function()
 {
     return false;
 });
```

All it does is cancels the mousedown event: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1357151/746754) about information for returning false from event handlers. It will prevent the default event from occurring and prevent the event from bubbling up to the other event handlers.